# Check if a child is present or not, and retrive simple data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is a my `firebase` database. Here in the first node I have a child **BeenThere**, and in the second I don't. I want to check if that **BeenThere** exists and if not create one, and if exists, how to retrieve it simply, without any model or callbacks? Is is possible?

Comment: All Firebase APIs that get data from the database involve callbacks.  There is no way to avoid that.

Comment: I tried with ValueEventListener, but it returns the result only if data is being added or modified. I want to read the data simply.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you've tried, and explain how it doesn't meet your needs.  The problem you're now describing sounds very different than the what you've written in your question so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: you are not able to read any data without a call back.**

Now you must understand the difference between the call backs in firebase, there is 3 (and all of these 3 are considered a data readers):

**Child added:**

Triggers when a child is added. (This is not what you need).

**Value Event Listener:**

Triggers when a child is added or modified. (This is not what you need).

**Listener for single value event:**

Triggers only once you attach it and does not triggers again (This is what you need).

So as you see now when ever you need to simply just read the data you must call `Listener for single value event`.

**Example:**

Lets say you want to check if `BeenThere` exists under a certain random id you have to do this:

```
//this is a method that you call when you need to read the node and do the check.

public void checkBeenThere(String random_id){

DatabaseReference places_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Places");

places_ref.child(random_id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot){

//check if Been there exist
if(datasnapshot.hasChild("BeenThere")){
//been there is found

//get the value of been there (THIS IS THE EDIT***).

 int been_there = datasnapshot.child("BeenThere").getValue(Integer.class); 




}else{
//been there is not found

//add it under the specific random id
places_ref.child(random_id).child("BeenThere").setValue(0);


}


}
@Override
public void onCnacelled(DatabaseError error){

}
});

}
```

If you are confused about the random_id, its just that id that you have in your database structure (ex:ChIJZZ.........), you need to pass that id to check if been there exist under it.

So lets say I want to check if been there exist under ChIJZZ.........., I do this:

```
//you must type the whole id, I added .... because it is long.
checkBeenThere("ChIJZZ_sM.......");
```

Comment: I'll try this and inform! Thank you for your time and answer:)

Comment: I got it. If it there, I can Check if BeenTherr is there, and if not set it to 0. But how to read that data? 
`dataSnapshot.child("BeenThere").getValue()` I  have tried and resulted in error.

Comment: @BikramNath I updated the code so you can get the value of the (BeenThere). The edit is found under the comment that includes (THIS IS THE EDIT**) in the onDataChange() method.

Comment: Such an wonderful people you are! This works perfectly. I tried and succeeded using a messy method, getting the data as string, then converting to int :D 
Thanks man:)